# Recognizing the requesting device for a web application

Tags: java

I have a web application which contains jsp pages for desktop and mobile devices in two separate folders in side WEB-INF, i.e. **WEB-INF/desktop** & **WEB-INF/mobile**. 
Based on the requesting device I want to redirect to the specified page. If the requesting device is mobile, it will be redirected to 
WEB-INF/mobile/login.jsp page otherwise it will be redirected to WEB-INF/desktop/login.jsp page. So my main challenge here is to identify the requesting device. Can anyone help me how can I achieve my target?

Comment: *"jsp pages"* similar to *"ATM machine"*..

Comment: If possible, try to make mobile pleasant sites using css instead - it will be a lot easier to mantain. Unless your sites content differs wildly depending on platform for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking "User-Agent" header in incoming request